# Run Hypersonic db on Tomee in server mode

Tags: java, hsqldb, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I am facing next issue. In my company we are moving Hypersonic db from Jboss to TomEE server (apache-tomee-plus-7.0.1). All necessary libraries, according to Hypersonic documentation are in lib directory of server (by default).

I want, when server is starting to start running Hypersonic database in server mode (on specific port) from configuration so that a webapp that is deployed on the same server can connect to it.

Here is our resource config in tomee.xml:

```xml
<Resource id="HSQLDB Database" type="DataSource">
    jdbcDriver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    jdbcUrl = jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:9001
    userName = sa
    password =
</Resource>
```

But when server is starting, we get next error:

```
org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=HSQLDB Database)
16-Sep-2016 13:14:05.145 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial    connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Can someone tell me what are we doing wrong and how do we successfully deploy Hypersonic db on Tomee in server mode?

Answer (score 2):

I see you have not specified the name of database and alias to be connected to. Both of the following URLs' should work well. HSQL database uses defaultly the port `9001`. If there haven't been set differently, all the followings URLs should work well:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/myDatabase
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:9001/myDatabase
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/myDatabase
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1/myDatabase
```

Before you connect to database with Java, you've to start your server up in a terminal:

```
java -cp C:/----/hsqldb-2.3.4/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:myDatabase --dbname.0 myDatabase
```

Don't forget to specify the full path to `hsqldb.jar`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. 
We managed to do this. I would also like to know if there is a way to avoid starting a separate hsql server in a terminal and to have hsql deployed on the same TomEE server where our WebApp is running?

Comment: Hmm, my only idea is to execute it as the command with Java directly.